# MKMapView turning off location services

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

i'm using a MKMapView with the "showsUserLocation" option in my application. I've added the mapview with interface builder and sets the showUserLocation option in viewDidAppear and viewWillDissappear.

The problem is when going back from the view or putting the application in background. The location services icon does not disappear. Actually i have to delete the application to make it disappear. Even if i manually force close the application it is still there and if i go into settings it is still active in the list of applications using location services.

I've added the relevant code below, what am i missing here?? Thanks in advance!

*.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ***viewController: UIViewController {   
    IBOutlet MKMapView *theMapView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *theMapView;
@end
```

*.m

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        theMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

        theMapView.showsUserLocation = NO;

    }

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];

    [theMapView release];
}
```

Comment: Add delegate to .h class and add self.theMapView.delegate = self;

Comment: Adding a delegate to the mapView didn't help, but thanks for the response.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If so, I'd love to know the solution.

Comment: I got it to work yes, but I'm not 100% of how i did it.. Try setting the delegate for the mapview to nil in the dealloc method and see if that works for you. I think that's what i did. If it works for you please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just guessing , this might not solve it but try adding self in both statement with self

i.e

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        self.theMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

        self.theMapView.showsUserLocation = NO;

    }
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Putting the MKMapView in tracking mode would turn on showsUserLocation but turning off tracking mode would not turn off showsUserLocation.  Setting it manually as above worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can register for notifications when the app goes into and comes out of background and save and restore the user location state respectively:

```
class MyVCWithAMap: UIViewController {
    ...
    // Track the state of the map user location property when going to background
    var trackUserLocation = false
    ...
    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        // Register for notifications
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(appEnteredForeground), name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(appEnteredBackground), name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func appEnteredBackground() {
        // Capture map user location state
        viewModel.trackUserLocation = mapView.showsUserLocation            
        mapView.showsUserLocation = false
    }

    func appEnteredForeground() {
        // Restore pre-snooze state
        mapView.showsUserLocation = viewModel.trackUserLocation
    }

}
```

Comment: Also - note that when you go to the background I've seen it take 10 or more seconds for the location indicator to go hollow (indicating recent access but not current)